# ASP.NET OWIN Identity Error AAD Auth Failure when SSL is Offloaded From Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, owin

I am using Azure Active Directory login via ASP.NET OWIN Identity for authentication.

I have a load balancer which is doing SSL offloading, so my server itself is running http protocol and not https protocol, but the load balancer is SSL.

I am getting this error:

```
[WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +1686
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.<GetResponseSyncOrAsync>d__2.MoveNext() +392
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.<SendPostRequestAndDeserializeJsonResponseAsync>d__0`1.MoveNext() +512

[AdalServiceException: AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50011: The reply address 'http://intx.mydomain.com/default' does not match the reply address 'https://intx.mydomain.com/default' provided when requesting Authorization code.
Trace ID: d5861c62-9d42-4f2b-886a-06cc63b01f00
Correlation ID: f77d0d3e-9dd2-4af8-a38f-65f7838bc680
Timestamp: 2018-10-28 05:13:16Z]
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.RunAsyncTask(Task`1 task) +133
   CloudmersiveAdminApp.Startup.<ConfigureAuth>b__10_0(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification context) in C:\Src\APIs\Account3\CloudmersiveAccount\CloudmersiveAdminApp\App_Start\StartupAuth.cs:109
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.<AuthenticateCoreAsync>d__1a.MoveNext() +5428
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.<AuthenticateCoreAsync>d__1a.MoveNext() +5937
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<BaseInitializeAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +817
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +329
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +768
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<RunApp>d__5.MoveNext() +196
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<DoFinalWork>d__2.MoveNext() +184
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar) +117
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +367
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +195
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +128
```

Note how it is complaining about the protocol being http and not https.  The thing is - in the browser, it is https!  It is just that the https part is being offloaded by the load balancer.

How can I configure ASP.NET to not throw this error?  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the exception, your problem might be related to reply URL specified in code/configuration.

Make sure that any request to Azure AD still specifies the redirect URL/reply URL to be `https://intx.mydomain.com/default`.

Usual suspects would be -

a. StartupAuth.cs (around line 109 as per stack trace). Check in that file wherever you have specified RedirectUri

b. Any other place in code where you try to acquire token and specify redirect URL explicitly.

If it still doesn't work out, try adding some more code details to your question about Startup configuration and Token acquire logic.